# Set page number in controller in pagination CakePHP 4.x

Tags: cakephp-4.x

Is it possible to set the page number programatically within the controller?
I have a searchform on a paginated index page.
Each time the user send a new search I want to reset the page number to 1.

In the request params there is 'page' with the current number, so when I paginate the query with the new search conditions the page number remains the same. I want it to be 1.

I tried set page in paginate array:

```
$this->paginate = array(
                            'limit'=> 20,
                            'order'=> array('Productions.id' => 'desc'),
                            'contain'=> array(
                                    'Products'=>'Units',
                                    'Telephely',
                                    'Leccsapat'
                                ),
                            'recursive'=> -1,
                            'conditions'=>$conditions,
                            'page'=> 1,
                            );
```

No success.

I tried

```
$this->paginate['offset']=0;
```

No success.

I tried also

```
public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    }
.
.
.
$this->Paginator->setConfig('page',1);
```

No success.
I can save the search condition in session, and then redirect in controller with page:1, but I prefer to do it in pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller try overwrite page number. Not very pretty, but effective:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->is('post')) {
    $queryParams = $this->getRequest()->getQueryParams();
    $queryParams['page'] = 1;
    $this->setRequest($this->getRequest()->withQueryParams($queryParams));
}
```